# how to change font of in TextView thats text is inside two asterisk ie **here**

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` where I am getting text from user I and I want that if user's input contain
two asterisk both side and text will in between ( ** ** ). so I want to change the **Font of the text that is in between** how can I do that?

for example in `StackOverFlow` if you put two asterisk or star it gets bold like this - **Bold Text Between Two Asterisk. You can't see stars or asterisk in this text but it is.**

> You can see a example of my case below:

[image: example]

#### NOTE:

User can enter multiple asterisk any where the user wants - for example
`In StackOverFlow` you can use Multiple time **bold** feature

The user input maybe something like this:

```
String userInput = "This is the Normal text 
**And this the text I want to in different font**
and again normal text and **Now Again the text the user want to in
different font** "
```

Answer (score 1):

Please just try to use this below way

```
    String text = "this is the text *Android* for developer test";
                SpannableStringBuilder strspan = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
                int start = text.toString().indexOf("**",0)+2;
                int end = text.toString().indexOf("**",start); //or  int end = text.toString().lastIndexOf("**");
                Typeface font = ResourceUtils.getFont(R.font.avenirnextltprodemi);
                strspan.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

yourtextview.setText(strspan);


public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

private final Typeface newType;

public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
    super(family);
    newType = type;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
}

private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
    int oldStyle;
    Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
    if (old == null) {
        oldStyle = 0;
    } else {
        oldStyle = old.getStyle();
    }

    int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
    if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }

    if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
        paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    }

    paint.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

}

**For multiple place inside string**

```
    boolean isanyasterisk = true
    SpannableStringBuilder strspan = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    int globalpos=0;
    int end;
    int start;
    while(isanyasterisk){
    
    if(globalpos>=string.length){
      isanyasterisk = false;
      return;
    }
    
    
    start = text.toString().indexOf("**",globalpos)+2;
    if(start>=0){
     end = text.toString().indexOf("**",start); 
    
      isanyasterisk=true;
      Typeface font =  ResourceCompat.getFont(context,R.font.avenirnextltprodemi); strspan.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 
  strspan.delete(start-2,start);
  strspan.delete(end,end+2);
    }else{
       isanyasterisk=false;
       break the loop or return
    }
    
     globalpos= end+2;
    
    }
```

Hope it may help you

Comment: thank you for responding I will try this code.

Comment: Please change `ResourceUtils.getFont(R.font.avenirnextltprodemi);` to `ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.avenirnextltprodemi);`. `ResourceUtils` is giving error

Comment: @Your answer is working but the star or asterisk is not get disappear. I want that asterisk is not visible by user enter two asterisk

Comment: please check my question again.

Comment: @Raaaaa please check the answer again I have updated the way of do this according to your requirement also you can manage the condition as you want. hope it may help you